# <img> and <p> with text same line, and <p> same height

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|         | Text: Hello, World! I am a paragraph |
|  Image  | with the same line and height of the |
|         | image                                |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to give  tag the style "inline-block" but that did nothing:

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png" alt="image" style="inline-block">
    <p>Hello, World! I am a paragraph with the same line and height of the image</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** `display:flex;` did the job, but I would like to add that I also used `align-self:center;` on the `<img>` so that the image won't stretch

Comment: display:flex on the div and you got it

Comment: Awesome! Thank you it worked!

Comment: @Paulie_D So you voted my answer down, which had been a better answer and the first one, but not the other one, so I thought I should delete my answer, and now look at this. An answer that's poorer of quality than mine got accepted too! Wow. Well done boss!

Comment: @pileup FWIW, I gave a better solution than the answer you accepted. I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: But I don't see any answer by you, I think you deleted it before I even saw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <img src="image.png" alt="image">
    <p>Hello, World! I am a paragraph with the same line and height of the image</p>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks, also added `align-self: center;` so that the image won't stretch